# Winui 3 NavigationView with nested tabs navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, winui-3, figma

I am pretty noob with WinUI 3 or generally in Desktop app development.

I am trying to achieve the exact result from the below image in WinUI 3 and c#. I have tried a lot of things but the result was not close.

Result to achieve:

[image: Wireframe]

- I have tried to create a Custom Navigation Pane with TabsView component but the style of tabs I couldn't change and won't work for the navigation's compact mode. There isn't any option to remove the tab's close button. The tabs won't be displayed icons in Navigations's compact mode.
- Tried also the Pivot control but didn't work
- Tried to change the tabs style but didn't work. Tried a lot of things, didn't work and don't remember me. Tried updating visual states but didn't work and ditched the tabs component because also of Navigation's compact mode( when Drawer is close and the left pane is shown with icons).
- Then, I tried also With ToggleButton buttons and dynaically

  ```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ToggleButton x:Name="Tab1Button" Content="Tab 1" Checked="OnTabChecked"/>
      <ToggleButton x:Name="Tab2Button" Content="Tab 2" Checked="OnTabChecked"/>
      <ToggleButton x:Name="Tab3Button" Content="Tab 3" Checked="OnTabChecked"/>
  </StackPanel>
  ```

  | Navigation view/drawer open | Navigation view/drawer closed |
  | --- | --- |
  | [image: 23+6] | [image: ...] |
- Tried to develop custom components using UserControl, CustomControl

  | Navigation view/drawer open | Navigation view/drawer closed |
  | --- | --- |
  | [image: 3comps] | [image: 3components together in close] |

  So here I have developed 3 controls: 2 user control and 1 Custom control but they are not close... 2 of them are but they are """compatible with NavigationMenu Items""". I want them to become icon buttons when Navigation is closed as in Wireframe.

```
<NavigationView.PaneCustomContent>
    <StackPanel>
        <CustomComponents:CustomTabControl x:Name="MyCustomTabControl"/>
        <CustomComponents:CustomButtonToggle x:Name="MyCustomButtonToggle"/>
        <CustomComponents:CustomButtonTogglePanel>
            <Button Content="Structure 2"/>
            <Button Content="Buildings 2"/>
            <Button Content="Assets 2"/>
        </CustomComponents:CustomButtonTogglePanel>
    </StackPanel>
    
</NavigationView.PaneCustomContent>
```

CustomTabControl

```
XAML: https://codefile.io/f/DNmrhpx0hw
XAML C#: https://codefile.io/f/2mGz8rGW27
```

CustomButtonTogglePanel

```
XAML: https://codefile.io/f/IefFxLbUe8
```

I have been trying to generate the code from Figma using plugins but there aren't any decent

I have been thinking to do something like but don't know whether this is correct approch or not and feasible

```
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
  <CustomComponent:CustomNavigationViewItem>
    <CustomComponent:CustomButtonToggleComponent> 
      <Button><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Icon>...</Icon><TextBlock>Structure</TextBlock></StackPanel><Button>
      <Button><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Icon>...</Icon><TextBlock>Building</TextBlock></StackPanel><Button>
    </CustomComponent:CustomButtonToggleComponent>
  </CustomComponent:CustomNavigationViewItem>
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

where CustomNavigationViewItem is the CustomControl component that extends the NavigationViewItem class. It will display the CustomButtonToggleComponent and on LeftCompact mode, CustomNavigationViewItem will get the content from CustomButtonToggleComponent and rerender the panel with only icons buttons from CustomButtonToggleComponent.

Or is it a bad idea? Is there any other better idea than this? Simple yet reusable?

Recap:  I want when the Navigation drawer is opened, the "Toggle Buttons" or "Tabs button" are shown horizontally with the active button or tab underlined as shown in the Wireframe Image above and when the navigation or navigation's drawer is closed or is in the Compact Mode, it should show that  "Toggle" or "Tabs" 's button vertically. Like as they would be normal `NavigationViewItem` elements.

[image: CompactMode]

Comment: It's hard to understand what your issue is. Do you mean you want to align the menu items horizontally when the pane is open, and align them vertically when the pane is closed?

Comment: I am sorry about that unable to explain my issue and yes when navigation drawer is open, it should show the "Toggle Buttons" or "Tabs button" shown horizontally with active button or tab underlined as it shown in the Wireframe Image and when the nav is close or is in Compact Mode, it should show that  "Toggle Buttons" or "Tabs button" vertically.

Comment: I think it is not a TabControl, Most likely, it is NavigationView control with Top display mode or a Pivot Control.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview#display-modes       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/pivot

Comment: I have forget to mention that I had tryied also pivot but that didn't work either... don't know how to do with compact mode.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with `NavigationView`.  You have to develop your own NavigationView custom control.  You may also try a user control with two `NavigationView` controls and merge or extract the items based on the mode, but that would be rather complex and error prone.

Comment: Can anybody provide me an example with UserControls, if possible?

Comment: For more details about UserControl, you could start from the Doc: [UserControl Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4)

Comment: I have this [video](https://youtu.be/AisI7MCVrC8) on my channel.